# Xamarin android can't find id field

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I am working on android using xamarin in visual studio 2015. I want to add a chart, so for basic understanding i followed up `oxyplot` and downloaded the documentation(sample code). Right now i am just copying the source code but by writing the code. When i reached the point `FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id)` i cant find the `Id` field in it. For better understanding please see the bellow image and code

[image]

Bellow is the code from which i am copying

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;

namespace AndroidApp1
{
  [Activity(Label = "AndroidApp1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        PlotView view = FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.plot_view);
        view.Model = CreatePlotModel();
    }

    private PlotModel CreatePlotModel()
    {
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot Demo" };

        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });

        var series1 = new LineSeries
        {
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 4,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White
        };

        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.0, 6.0));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.4, 2.1));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2.0, 4.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3.3, 2.3));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.7, 7.4));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6.0, 6.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8.9, 8.9));

        plotModel.Series.Add(series1);

        return plotModel;
    }
}}
```

Bellow is the in which i am writing

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;


namespace SampleChart
{
[Activity(Label = "SampleChart", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        PlotView view = FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id)
    }
}}
```

I don't know what am i missing. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide your Main.axml layout so we can ensure you have the View and id set correctly?  You should have "android:id="@+id/plot_view"" in your <PlotView> view.

Answer (score 1):

The ID you are trying to access has to be defined in a Xml file 
something like this

> `android:id="@+id/Content"

so that you can point out to the resource which has the ID , or it either has to be refined in another file something like values->id.xml

Comment: Id should be created in ID Class in resources.cs but it's not there